# How to print PDF with Not default printer with code (VB Net)

Tags: vb.net, printing

I´m trying to print a pdf file, there is no problem to print it with the default printer but when I want to do it with a secondary printer it still printing with the default one.

This is my code:

```
 Dim MyProcess As New Process
 MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
 MyProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "print"

 'HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE PRINTER (BUT THIS COMMAND IS IGNORED)
 MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "Canon MG3500 series"

 MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
 MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Copias digitales\Temp.pdf"
 MyProcess.Start()
 MyProcess.WaitForExit(10000)
 MyProcess.CloseMainWindow()
 MyProcess.Close()
```

How can I make it?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Printer Settings.Printername](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printername(v=vs.110).aspx) under the Namespace  [System.Drawing.Printing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing(v=vs.110).aspx)

then specify the name of your Printer ( "Canon MG3500 series")

> The **PrinterSettings** control is used to configure how a document is printed by specifying the printer.<sup>[source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_print_dialog.htm)</sup>

This should do it.

note: This also allows you to use your *applied* settings on your printer (

```
i.e. Paper size
```

I use this everytime I need to use two printers

`i.e one for the O.R. then another for a document`

[Here is a good example](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/68137.aspx) of using this along with a `combobox` to choose any printer in the network.

Comment: Thanks Myk but I found the solution replacing the bad line for: Shell(String.Format("rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n ""{0}""", "Printer name"))

Comment: Glad you could resolve the error. It's in one of the [examples here](http://vbcity.com/forums/p/68137/273274.aspx#273274)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution replacing the bad line with:

```
Shell(String.Format("rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n ""{0}""", "Printer name"))
```